# Problems with proving that a sequence converges to some certain limit

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

So here is my problem,

I would like the prove the following,

For any $m=0,1,2...$ and for $\alpha\in \mathbb C$ with $\Re(\alpha)<0$ it holds that,
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}t^me^{-\alpha t}=0$$
Since I am unfortunately not yet common with handeling complex numbers I thought i try it out first for $m=0$ to check why the satement holds.

Then I obtained the following,

Let $\alpha=-x+iy$ with $x\in\mathbb R_+\backslash\{0\}$ and $y\in\mathbb R$ sucht that $\Re(\alpha)<0$. Then for $m=0$ it follows that,
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}e^{-\alpha t}=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{e^{\alpha t}}=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{e^{-xt}e^{iyt}}=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{e^{xt}}{e^{iyt}}=\frac{e^{x}}{e^{iy}}\neq0$$
I am sure i made a fundamental mistake somewhere but i dont see where.

Could someone help me? And if its possible without telling me the whole prove, I would like to try it by my self... Thanks!

Comment: Either there is no minus sign in the exponential's exponent or else $\;\text{Re}(\alpha)>0\;$ , otherwise that limit cannot be zero

Comment: So the assumption in the exercise sheet was wrong :D thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $\;t\in\Bbb R_+\;$ **and** $\;\text{Re}(\alpha)>0$:

$$\left|t^me^{-\alpha t}\right|=t^me^{-\text{Re}(\alpha)t}\xrightarrow[t\to\infty]{}0$$